# Solving functional equation $F(x) = F(x^2 + 1)$ to prove that $F(x)$ is differentiable

Tags: integration, functions

Show that there exists a non-zero continuous function $f$ satisfying: $\int_a^{a^2 + 1} f(x) dx = 0$ for all real $a$.

By letting $F'(x) = f(x)$, I have got that $F(x) = F(x^2 + 1)$, which implies that $F(x)$ is even, so $f(x)$ is odd.

I am stuck when it comes to showing that $f(x)$ is continuous (or equivalently that $F(x)$ is differentiable) using the information I currently have.

Is it necessary to find explicit expressions for $F(x)$ and / or $f(x)$ or is it possible to solve the problem without doing so? [I have tried guessing functions for $F(x)$ and using a series solution, but neither approach has worked.]

Comment: You can't prove $f(x)$ is non-zero, because the constant zero function satisfies this integral equation. You also can't show it's continuous - changing its value at one point will not violate the property.

Comment: Also $f$ being continuous is not equivalent to $F$ being differntiable. $F$ is always differentiable (by definition) if exists. Which also brings the question: why do you think that $f$ has an antiderivative? Without the assumption that $f$ is continuous this may not be true.

Comment: @Wojowu What I meant was that assuming that $f(x)$ is not the zero function, show that the function is continuous - I can see that $f(x) = 0$ would satisfy the given integral

Comment: @Wojowu Also I'm confused about why I can't show that $f(x)$ is continuous

Comment: Take $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 1$ and $f(1)=1$. This is a discontinuous function also satisfying the equation.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear what I am being asked to prove.

Comment: That makes more sense, if you just want to show there _exists_ such a function $f$.

Comment: The function $f$ must satisfy $2xf(x^2+1)=f(x)$.

Comment: @egreg Is that enough to show that there exists a function $f$ which satisfies the given integral?